# Create a tuple with variatic type wrapped

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, metaprogramming

Today I'm trying to create a tuple a little specific (for me at least) and at compile time.

I have some basic struct, let say :

```
struct Foo1 { int data; };
struct Foo2 { int data; };
struct Foo3 { int data; };
```

And another struct but with some template stuff :

```
template < typename T,
           size_t Size >
struct Metadata {

  using type = T;

  std::bitset<Size>  bitset;
};
```

So now I want to create this kind of tuple :

```
constexpr std::tuple<Metadata<Foo1, 3>, Metadata<Foo2, 3>, Metadata<Foo3, 3>> test { {0}, {0}, {0}};
```

But in an automatic way, more like:

```
template < typename ... Ts >
constexpr auto make_metadata() {

  return std::tuple<Metadata<Foo1, sizeof...(Ts)>, 
                    Metadata<Foo2, sizeof...(Ts)>,
                    Metadata<Foo3, sizeof...(Ts)>>{{0},{0},{0}};
}
```

Well the last code is far from good, so I'd like to have something like that but automatic. Maybe with tuple_cat and fold expression, but I'm a little lost. So if somebody know the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `...` to mean multiple things in a single expression. In this case, you want to expand `Ts` both immediately and non-immediately:

```
template <class... Ts>
constexpr auto make_metadata()
{
    return std::make_tuple(Metadata<Ts, sizeof...(Ts)>{0}...);
}
```

Also, you don't *have* to write everything on a single line if it makes it clearer for you to write it this way:

```
template <class... Ts>
constexpr auto make_metadata()
{
    constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(Ts);
    return std::make_tuple(Metadata<Ts, N>{0}...);
}
```

Comment: Seems like with C++17 I won't have to put std::make_tuple explicitly. But thanks to you and Guillaume anyway :)

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel Sure, you'd be able to save 5 chars and just write `std::tuple(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple variadic template expansion with `std::make_tuple` will suffice:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto make_metadata() {
    return std::make_tuple(Metadata<Ts, sizeof...(Ts)>{0}...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want:

```
template <typename T> struct tag {};

template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto make_metadata() {

  return std::tuple<Metadata<Ts, sizeof...(Ts)>...>{{(tag<Ts>{}, 0)}...};
}
```