# How pass the same struct with different template argument as parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, constexpr

Thanks to SO guys I resolved one of my problem:
[Create a tuple with variatic type wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576659/create-a-tuple-with-variatic-type-wrapped/41576844?noredirect=1#comment70359563_41576844)

But I realized after that, I still have a problem that I can't solve.
So now I have :

```
template < typename T,
           size_t Size >
struct Metadata {

  using type = T;

  std::bitset<Size>  bitset;
};

template <class... Ts>
constexpr auto make_metadata()
{
    constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(Ts);
    return std::make_tuple(Metadata<Ts, N>{0}...);
}
```

I intent to use it "like" that :

```
constexpr auto result = make_metadata<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3>({0}, {0}, {0});
```

And according to [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) comment, I think I'll need 2 functions.

But how I can **pass the arguments to the function and then to the tuple?**

And I wonder how do that but **without force to pass each arguments for each Ts**, if they are not present I'll just put a default value (**2 questions**).

Comment: Pass a tuple for each constructor (that you can unpack if desired in helper function).

Comment: It's not very clear what you want, can you add an example of how to use it?

Comment: @Jarod42 in fact I just can put a tuple (like in your answer) as an argument, and then concat with default value if needed?

Comment: I mean something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a6ebfdeb372962c).

Comment: @Jarod42 Well far better that I'm writing :) Thanks

Comment: why the argument is `{{0}, {0}, {0}}` not `{0},{0},{0}` (or `{},{},{}`)?

Comment: @appleapple don't worry about that, like I said it's an illustration. Well I'll replace it with {},{},{} to be sure. Thanks

Comment: you probably want `template <class... Ts> constexpr auto make_metadata(Ts...args);`.

Comment: and I really don't see why you need to provide argument since `Metadata` never use them

Comment: @appleapple you make me misunderstand myself. Sorry, {0} was to init Metadata<Foo1> ! I tried so many things but I don't think I need extra {} too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be what you want, I am not sure. (since you never show where the arguments to be used)

---

```
#include <tuple>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

struct A{int value;};
struct B{int value;};
struct C{int value;};

template <typename T,int Size>
struct Metadata{
  using type = T;
  T value;
  std::bitset<Size> bitset;
};

template <typename...Ts,typename...Args>
constexpr auto make_metadata(Args... args)
{
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Ts);
    return std::make_tuple(Metadata<Ts, N>{args,0}...);
}

int main(){
   auto data = make_metadata<A,B,C>(1,2,3);
   std::cout << "(" << std::get<0>(data).value.value 
             << ", " << std::get<1>(data).value.value
             << ", " << std::get<2>(data).value.value << ")";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but you're instantiate struct A,B and C. I don't want that, just Metadata<A,3> for your case, or Metadat<B,3>. Seems like I need to write a better question, because everybody did that even if I didn't ask for it.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel they are `Metadata`s, that's why I need to access the value by `.value.value`

Comment: and your `Metadata` do not take argument, do you want to initialize the `bitset`?

Comment: Oh you changed Metadata, didn't see that sorry. I'm going to try it then. Just need to remove the 0 inside make_metadata I think. I initialize the Metadata with {0} in the example so bitset = 0.

Comment: BTW, `args` is used to initialize `value`, and `0` is used to initialize `bitset`.

Comment: Well this is working even removing things I don't need (T value, and 0). I tried the same thing, just I let {1}, {2}, {3} in the call function. I need to use tuple more often I think. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: You are welcome, BTW, you can probably just use `1,2,3` (without curly bracket)